# vscode fake error: 'fa-icon' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, font-awesome

I have a problem with vscode, I'm getting an error:

```
'fa-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ng
```

but I've already imported it in the module "app.module" and this component (called "base") is a part of the root module.

this problem is only in vscode and the application is running without any errors.

[image: The Error]

**the code:**

base.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faFacebook, faInstagram, faTelegram } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
})
export class BaseComponent {

  facebook = faFacebook;
  instagram = faInstagram;
  telegram = faTelegram;

}
```

base.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand">
      Quiz App
    </a>
    <div class="text-light float-end fs-5">
      <a href="#"><fa-icon class="text-light p-1" [icon]="facebook"></fa-icon></a>
      <a href="#"><fa-icon class="text-light p-1" [icon]="instagram"></fa-icon></a>
      <a href="#"><fa-icon class="text-light p-1" [icon]="telegram"></fa-icon></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BaseComponent } from './base/base.component';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { HomeComponent } from './views/home/home.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BaseComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Potential fix: make a module for base.component and import it to app.module and list in imports [ ].

Comment: @MishaMashina I tryed that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting VS code, those errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this?

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

Comment: it's an angular app